# how do i assign a static method to a System.Delegate object?

Tags: c#, static, delegates

My problem is that i have a class whose constructor takes a System.Delegate object as a parameter and i have no idea how to assign a method to a System.Delegate object.
This is the code i have right now

```
class TestClass
{
    Delegate c = TestMetod;
    static void TestMetod()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("it worked !");
    }
}
```

but that doesn' t work because, oddly enough, System.Delegate is a non-delegate type as stated by msdna. 
How am i supposed to do what i need since it is impossible to "assign method group TestMetod to non-delegate type 'System.Delegate'"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `static` aspect is not the core issue here. You need a (any) delegate to capture TestMethod and then you can assign that to a System.Delegate. You can use `Action` as such an intermediate.

```
class TestClass
{
    static Action a = TestMetod;
    static Delegate c = a;
    static void TestMetod()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("it worked !");
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked ! but is there a way to avoid the use of an Action ?

Comment: @user1909612 Sure, just use any other delegate in existance.  There's nothing special about `Action`, but you need *some* type of delegate to be used.

Comment: `Action()` is just the easiest way to match `void TestMethod()`.

Comment: I'd use `Delegate c = new Action(TestMethod)` instead of introducing a helper field.